# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'coordinates1'

Tags: python

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import csv
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='******************')

input = open('geocodes.csv','r')
output = open('geocodesres.csv', 'w')

try:

    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output)



for row in reader:

    print(row)
    coordinates1, coordinates2 = [float(c) for c in row]


    my_location = gmaps.reverse_geocode(coordinates1,coordinates2)

    writer.writerow(my_location)

finally:
    input.close()
    output.close()
```

This is the error I have

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'coordinates1'

The input file contains longitude and latitude information for geocode. This is an excerpt from it:

```
coordinates1    coordinates2 
-74.0064354 40.6548713 
-73.98696542    40.75470191 
-73.99653   40.750742 
-73.957836  40.7222889 
-73.86747837    40.89872539 
-74.0064354 40.6548713 
-73.92064   40.81161
```

Comment: Post a snippet from the input file?

Comment: coordinates1 coordinates2
-74.0064354 40.6548713
-73.98696542 40.75470191
-73.99653 40.750742
-73.957836 40.7222889
-73.86747837 40.89872539
-74.0064354 40.6548713
-73.92064 40.81161

Comment: From your error, it seems as though it is trying to convert 'coordinates1' to a float.

Comment: hi @shyam, welcome to SO. Please read the following on how to create a [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: hi @chris all I want to do is read the coordinates, run the function and return the address from the reverse geocode

Comment: Yes, but the first line of your file is not a set of coordinates, something you have to account for.

Comment: @chris i tried deleting it. It still giving the same error.

Comment: @shinoda There are numerous errors in your implementation, including inconsistent spacing in the CSV file.  But that was the first error you were running in to.

Answer (score 0):

Consume the first row with the string `coordinates1    coordinates2`, using `next`:

```
reader = csv.reader(input)
next(reader)
```

because it cannot be converted into floats.